# Ler vários valores e calcular a média

Tags: c

Nesse algoritmo se eu escrevo `10`, `10` e depois `-1` para encerrar ele calcula `9.5`.

Nenhuma divisão dá exatamente o resultado que deveria ser, ou é o meu algoritmo que está escrito errado?

O exercício seria esse:

> Escreva um algoritmo que calcule a idade média de um grupo de pessoas. Ao final deve ser apresentada a quantidade de pessoas e a média de idade delas. O algoritmo encerra quando for digitado -1 para a idade.

OBS: preciso usar o `while` para resolver. O código em si está funcionando, mas a divisão não dá um número exato, ou pelo menos mais perto do que deveria ser.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float media=0;
int pessoas=0, idade=0;

int main()
{
    do{
        printf("Digite a sua idade (-1 para encerrar): ");
        scanf("%d", &idade);
        media = media + idade;
        pessoas++;

    if (idade < -1){
        printf("Digite uma idade valida\n");
        pessoas--;
    }

    }while(idade != -1);

    printf("A idade media do grupo e: %.1f\n", media/(pessoas-1));
    printf("O numero de pessoas no grupo e: %d\n", pessoas-1);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que quando é digitado `-1`, você soma esse valor na média, então no seu teste (digitando `10`, `10` e `-1`) o valor da variável `media` é 19. Por isso a média acaba sendo `9.5`.

Você só deveria somar o valor e incrementar o contador de pessoas se a idade for válida, assim você não precisa decrementar a quantidade de pessoas nos casos inválidos e o código fica mais simples:

```
int idade, qtd_pessoas=0, soma=0;
while(1){
    printf("Digite a sua idade (-1 para encerrar): ");
    scanf("%d", &idade);
    if (idade == -1) break;
    if (idade < -1){
        printf("Digite uma idade valida\n");
    } else {
        soma += idade;
        qtd_pessoas++;
    }
}
printf("A idade media do grupo e: %.1f\n", (float) soma / qtd_pessoas);
printf("O numero de pessoas no grupo e: %d\n", qtd_pessoas);
```

`while(1)` cria um loop infinito (pois valores diferentes de zero são considerados "verdadeiros"), e ele só é interrompido pelo `break` (que por sua vez só ocorre se a idade for -1, que é a condição de parada do loop).

Repare que assim, ao final do loop o contador de pessoas terá o valor correto e você não precisará subtrair 1.

Também mudei o nome da variável de `media` para `soma`, pois é isso que ela representa. A média só é calculada no final, ao dividir a soma pela quantidade de pessoas (e se for só para imprimir e nada mais, nem precisa de uma variável para isso).

O detalhe é que `soma` é um inteiro, pois estou somando as idades que também são inteiros. Mas ao fazer a divisão eu fiz um cast para `float` caso contrário a divisão não teria casas decimais.

Comment: Ah! entendi, voce poderia so me explicar pq no while voce colocou so (1)? se for o que eu estou pensando isso pode ajudar nos outros exercicios.. pq eu so aprendi a usar o while com alguma condicao dentro.

Comment: @LucianoBalestrinCorrea Atualizei a resposta com a explicação

Answer (score 0):

O erro está acontecendo porque você está passando o -1 para a variável `idade`, portanto sua média  está passando o valor 19 para o `printf`. Para corrigir isto coloque uma estrutura `if` dentro do seu `do..while`;

Seu código ficará assim:

```
  do{
        printf("Digite a sua idade (-1 para encerrar): ");
        scanf("%d", &idade);

    if(idade >= 0){
        pessoas++;
        media = media + idade;
        }

    else if (idade < -1){
        printf("Digite uma idade valida\n");
        pessoas--;

         }

    }while(idade != -1);
```

Comment: O que eu fiz ali em cima agora deu certo, o 10, 10 e -1, agora deu 10.. porem se agora eu coloco 10, 10, -2, -1 a idade media fica um erro: 1.$ e o numero de pessoas fica 1

Comment: @LucianoBalestrinCorrea a resposta do Hkotsubo ta perfeita! implemente-a, a não ser que seu professor pediu para fazer com `do..while` e modifico a minha respota, se não baseie-se na outra resposta

Comment: Na verdade, o meu professor pediu ou while ou do while

Comment: @LucianoBalestrinCorrea sobre sua dúvida do while, em grossas palavras: C interpreta 0 como false e todos os outros numeros como TRUE, então o while ficará ETERNAMENTE repetindo, talvez vc me pergunte: e como sai do laço? Atraves da instrução `break`.